# Scheme cannot define function

Tags: scheme, lisp

I have such a code, I've checked my braces, but still have no clue why the compiler gives me

> #f is not a function [sumOfSqaresOfTwoBiggest, (anon)]

error

```
(
  define (sumOfSqaresOfTwoBiggest a b c) (
    cond (
      ((and (> a c ) (> b c)) (+ (* a a) (* b b)))
      ((and (> a b) (> c b)) (+ (* a a) (* c c)))
      (else (+ (* a a) (* c c)))
    )
  )
)
(sumOfSqaresOfTwoBiggest 1 2 3)
```

Comment: a good idea would be to use standard Lisp formatting and not inventing your own. Thus you will not train to recognize standard Lisp construct formatting. Especially C-like formatting will be misleading. Lisp is not structure like C code.

Comment: For a clue about your problem: count the parentheses after `COND`. How many are there and is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a rather unusual way of formatting lisp code. In fact, using an editor tailored for this kind of code will help you a lot to avoid this kind of errors, which is, yes, a wrong parenthesis.

Here is a correct version with the usual indentation:

```
(define (sumOfSqaresOfTwoBiggest a b c)
  (cond ((and (> a c ) (> b c)) (+ (* a a) (* b b)))
        ((and (> a b) (> c b)) (+ (* a a) (* c c)))
        (else (+ (* a a) (* c c)))))

(sumOfSqaresOfTwoBiggest 1 2 3)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Also, I cannot find any tutorials so I could install Scheme interpreter on my machine, so I use online version of it, which has no syntax highlight. Do you know any good tutorials that could help me with that?

Comment: You could use DrRacket as a comprehensive environment to learn the dialect of scheme that you prefer. See [this link](https://racket-lang.org).

Comment: This fails for the test case, and whenever `b` and `c` are the two largest numbers: `(else (+ (* a a) (* c c)))` --> `(else (+ (* b b) (* c c)))`.